# AzureSignTool sh: command not found when run in an Azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: azure-pipelines, code-signing

I have a pipeline that was running successfully and deploying my software to a container. I wanted to add code signing to the exe created by the build stage before it is published in the ACA.

Our certificate is held in a key vault and I am attempting to use AzureSignTool to sign the exe file as a test before deployment.

Following the walkthrough for [AzureSignTool](https://github.com/vcsjones/AzureSignTool/blob/main/WALKTHROUGH.md) you need to add two tasks to your pipeline. The first installs AzureSignTool and the second runs the command to sign the file(s) you want to sign. The problem I have is that after installing the tool I get this error:

sh: line 1: AzureSignTool: command not found

It is a global install and I can't understand why it can't be found?

One thing to note is an ex colleague wrote the original pipeline and chose to use Unbunto. I am used to writing pipelines that use Windows Server, so not sure if this makes a big difference.

A cut down version of the pipeline:

```
trigger:
  tags:
    include:
    - '*'
  branches:
    include:
    - develop
    - release/*

variables:
  - group: 'CodeSigningVariables' #variable group
  
pool: ubuntu-20.04

stages:

  # Build Project
  - stage: Build
    displayName: Build & Test Project
    jobs:
      - job: Build
        steps:
          - checkout: self
            persistCredentials: true
            clean: true

          - #### BUILD SECTION REDACTED ####

          - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
            displayName: 'Install AzureSignTool'
            inputs:
              command: custom
              custom: tool
              arguments: 'update --global azuresigntool'
              
          - task: CmdLine@2
            displayName: 'Sign Application'
            inputs:
              script: |
                AzureSignTool sign -kvu $(SigningVaultURL) -kvi $(SigningClientId) -tr $(SigningTimeStamp) -kvt $(SigningTennentId) -kvs $(SigningClientSecret) -kvc $(SigningCertName) -v $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/src/Project/bin/Release/Project.exe
```

The output from the 'Install AzureSignTool' step:

```
Starting: Install AzureSignTool
==============================================================================
Task         : .NET Core
Description  : Build, test, package, or publish a dotnet application, or run a custom dotnet command
Version      : 2.221.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli
==============================================================================
Info: .NET Core SDK/runtime 2.2 and 3.0 are now End of Life(EOL) and have been removed from all hosted agents. If you're using these SDK/runtimes on hosted agents, kindly upgrade to newer versions which are not EOL, or else use UseDotNet task to install the required version.
/usr/bin/dotnet tool update --global azuresigntool
Skipping NuGet package signature verification.
Tool 'azuresigntool' was reinstalled with the latest stable version (version '4.0.1').
Info: Azure Pipelines hosted agents have been updated and now contain .Net 5.x SDK/Runtime along with the older .Net Core version which are currently lts. Unless you have locked down a SDK version for your project(s), 5.x SDK might be picked up which might have breaking behavior as compared to previous versions. You can learn more about the breaking changes here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/ and https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/ . To learn about more such changes and troubleshoot, refer here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops#troubleshooting
Finishing: Install AzureSignTool
```

The output from the 'Sign Application' step:

```
Starting: Sign Application
==============================================================================
Task         : Command line
Description  : Run a command line script using Bash on Linux and macOS and cmd.exe on Windows
Version      : 2.231.1
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line
==============================================================================
Generating script.
Script contents:
AzureSignTool sign -kvu https://keyvault.vault.azure.net/ -kvi *** -tr http://timestamp.digicert.com -kvt *** -kvs *** -kvc CertName -v /datadrive/agent/11/s/src/Project/bin/Release/Project.exe
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
/usr/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /datadrive/agent/_temp/b365c9f0-b063-4456-84b0-ab382de1b5ac.sh
/datadrive/agent/_temp/b365c9f0-b063-4456-84b0-ab382de1b5ac.sh: line 1: AzureSignTool: command not found

##[error]Bash exited with code '127'.
Finishing: Sign Application
```

Any help with this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the error output from the `Sign Application` step,  the command line task is invoking bash, the pipeline is running on the `Ubuntu linux` agent.

[image]

You should run the pipeline on `Windows` type agent so that it can be found. It's **windows only** as per the [doc](https://github.com/vcsjones/AzureSignTool/blob/main/README.md#requirements).

[image]

On linux agent, the tool cannot be found.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I have switched to Windows and it recognises the command. New problem now is it can't find the file I'm trying to sign, but I can figure that out.

Comment: Glad to know it help! Could you please help to [mark it as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) as the issue is resolved?  Thank you and wish you a lovely day!